# How do you replace a char in front of another with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text as:

```
0.1.Contents
0.2.Introduction
0.3.Document History
0.3.1.Document 1 History
```

I want:

```
0.1 Contents
0.2 Introduction
0.3 Document History
0.3.1 Document 1 History
```

Replacing .[a-z] with a blank space replaces the letter also

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this as notepad++ doesn't support lookarounds

```
search: "(\d+.\d+).(\w+)"
replace: "\1 \2"
```

Or even less specific as you pointed out

```
search: "\.([a-z])"
replace: " \1"
```

Comment: Is there a way of replacing all dots between a number and a letter with a space so '1.C' -> '1 C'? as I can have another line like: 0.3.1.Document 1 History

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a lookahead `(?=..)`:

```
search: \.(?=[a-z])
replace: " "
```

For a less permissive pattern that match only when you have a digit before, you can add a lookbehind:

```
search: (?<=\d)\.(?=[a-z])
replace: " "
```

Note that too old versions of notepad++ don't have these features.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this worked in the end:

Replace:

```
\.([^\d])
```

with:

```
 \1
```